# Preferred way to move around in vim (normal mode)

Tags: vim

I haven't seen this asked on stackoverflow, and this is my biggest pain point in vim:

How do you all navigate within a file?  I found myself using the hjkl too much, or too repetitively, and I want to get better at this.  This is frustrating when you're on a large monitor.

I installed EasyMotion - and so far it's been good for me - I just want to know if there's something better...

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I like the [cheatsheet of Ted Naleid](http://www.naleid.com/2010/10/04/vim-movement-shortcuts-wallpaper.html). It's like a reticle so you can easily find the horizontal and vertical movements. Put it on a wall next to your monitor and you will soon pick up new movements on the fly.

The movements that I liked recently are:

- () and {} which let you hop function wise in source code
- / and ? + n/N just search, you normally know where you want to go
- fx and tx - to jump to or before the next character x
  of course you can do a 2fx to jump to the second occurrence of x, like you can do with all movements
- % to move between starting and ending parenthesis

Comment: +1 this cheatsheet is smart, easy to understand and good looking.

Comment: For a long time I had it saved in my desktop.

Comment: For those in 2020 and onward, You can still find this wallpaper on archive.org
https://web.archive.org/web/20171028001200/www.naleid.com/2010/10/04/vim-movement-shortcuts-wallpaper.html

Answer (score 10):

I use `b` and `w` to move left and right respectively on a single line.  For up and down, I use `Ctrl+u` and `Ctrl+d` respectively.  IMO `Ctrl+u` and `Ctrl+d` are better than `Ctrl+b` and `Ctrl+f` because they scroll half window at a time so that you don't loose context.

I haven't really used any plugin for moving around in vim so far.

Forgot to mention two other important keystrokes, `$` and `^` to move to end of line and start of line respectively.

Answer (score 8):

Several move commands:

```
b B e E f F ge gE gj gk go G h H j k l L M n N t T w W { } / ? ^ $ # * ` ' | %
```

Learn them, plus all commands starting with `[` like `[{` which is very useful when editing C-style code…

See `:help index.txt` for reference.

Answer (score 5):

Mostly I use the following (in order of frequency):

- <kbd>'*R*</kbd> go to marked position (the <kbd>`</kbd> is too off the baseline keyboard to use much)
- <kbd>/*search*</kbd>|<kbd>?*search*</kbd>  forward|backward search
- <kbd>n</kbd>|<kbd>N</kbd> next|previous in search
- <kbd>H</kbd>|<kbd>L</kbd>|<kbd>M</kbd>  top|bottom|middle of display
- <kbd>G</kbd>  go to end of file
- <kbd>1G</kbd> go to line 1
- <kbd>{</kbd> go backward a 'paragraph' (often a code block)
- <kbd>}</kbd> go forward one 'paragraph'

Most all of these can be augmented with a count before the command.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you want to move around, but generally,

- `A` puts you in insert mode at the end of a line
- `I` at the beginning
- `o` inserts a line below
- `O` above

and more powerfully, searching with `/<thing you want to jump to>` is very handy. In a c file where the functions are formatted

```
int
funcname()
```

`/^funcname` will jump you to the start of the function. There's a bunch more, but this shold be a good start for someone new to vim.

Answer (score 2):

Simple documentation:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_around

Regular movement:
hjkl/arrow keys/page up/page down
`%` will switch between open/ending braces
gg/G move to top/bottom

Folding:
For collapsing large blocks of code, you can use folding.
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html

Search:
To jump to something in particular type `/searchstring` (use with `set inc` for jumping to matches while typing)
`*` to search forward for the same word the cursor is on
`#` same but search backward

You can also use marks.
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks

I also use ctags and jumping to find stuff across multiple files.
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html

I've never needed anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see much to add in terms of general enlightenment but I use (ranked by how often I use them):

```
w and b
```

to move by one word to the right and to the left.

```
/ and ?
```

to search for a word or pattern to the bottom or to the top.

```
G and gg
```

to jump to the bottom and the top of the buffer.

```
<C-f> and <C-b>
```

to jump to the next and previous screen.

```
* and #
```

to jump to next and previous occurence of the word under the cursor.

```
f and F
```

to jump before a character to the right or to the left.

```
t and T
```

to jump on a character to the right or to the left.

Ho! and

```
$ and ^
```

a lot, too, to jump to the end and the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Read http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html and run vimtutor, also :help motion.txt will be usefull. I recommend also staying in normal mode all the time - as described in article above. Generally, learning vim is learning piano - you have to practice much.